# scp command returned `no such file or directory` error

Tags: ssh, scp

I am trying to copy files from my laptop to a host via `ssh` command:

```
roberto@xxxxx1:~$ scp /home/roberto/Metagenoma_MEL_COLS/Mix-MEL_S10_L002_R1_001.fastq.tar.gz roberto@xxxx.xxx.xxx.es:/media/disk7/roberto/
```

and it shows:

```
/home/roberto/Metagenoma_MEL_COLS/Mix-MEL_S10_L002_R1_001.fastq.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

The output of `ls -lsa` is:

```
$ ls -lsa /home/roberto/Metagenoma_MEL_COLS/Mix-MEL_S10_L002_R1_001.fa‌​stq.tar.gz 
3268104 -rw------- 1 roberto roberto 3346533319 abr 27 07:01 /home/roberto/Metagenoma_MEL_COLS/Mix-MEL_S10_L002_R1_001.fa‌​stq.tar.gz
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: For me this error occurs: `No command 'Scp' found, [...]`. What's the output of `ls -la /home/me/folder/file.tar.gz'. Does it exsist? Do you have permissions on the file ? Beware. File names are case sensitive. And Spaces in File names bring problems. If so, try putting quotes around.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to run the `scp` command from the Server, but you must issue it from your Laptop:

```
roberto@roberto-VirtualBox:~$ scp /home/roberto/Metagenoma_MEL_COLS/Mix-MEL_S10_L002_R1_001.fastq.tar.gz roberto@xxxx.xxx.xxx.es:/media/disk7/roberto/
```

instead of

```
roberto@xxxxx1:~$ scp /home/roberto/Metagenoma_MEL_COLS/Mix-MEL_S10_L002_R1_001.fastq.tar.gz roberto@xxxx.xxx.xxx.es:/media/disk7/roberto/
```

From the Server you could run the following, but a firewall/router might prevent that.

```
roberto@xxxxx1:~$ scp roberto@roberto-VirtualBox:/home/roberto/Metagenoma_MEL_COLS/Mix-MEL_S10_L002_R1_001.fastq.tar.gz /media/disk7/roberto/
```

Comment: No problem :-) if the answer helped you, you could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Note: the `scp` command should be used with lowercase (I guess that it is a typo in your question).

The below message:

> /home/me/folder/file.tar.gz: No such file or directory

Means that the file you are trying to copy doesn't exists.

You can verify by running `ls -lsa` on this file

```
ls -lsa /home/me/folder/file.tar.gz
```

If the running `ls` on the file won't return a valid information about the file, it means that you had a typo in the filename and or the path

Comment: roberto@roberto-VirtualBox[roberto] ls -lsa /home/roberto/Metagenoma_MEL_COLS/Mix-MEL_S10_L002_R1_001.fastq.tar.gz  
3268104 -rw------- 1 roberto roberto 3346533319 abr 27 07:01 /home/roberto/Metagenoma_MEL_COLS/Mix-MEL_S10_L002_R1_001.fastq.tar.gz

Comment: the file permissions seems to be ok, what happened when you use the same path in the `scp` command (e.g. by using cut&paste) to avoid typos in the file-path? do you still get the `no such file` error?

Comment: @RobertoVeliz - if you get the error again, please [edit] your question with the actual `scp` command you are running with the full-path-name as you did for the `ls -lsa` command, so we might help you find typos if exists.

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: thanks for updating, now I think we can help, see my answer